# Prevent non-administrators from logging in on Windows for a specific period of time

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Here is my scenario. My application does some maintenance stuff during which only administrators should be allowed to login to Windows.

After the maintenance is done, any user should be able to login.

What is a good solution to this problem ? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: OS is Windows 7

thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: lookup GINA DLL, that might give you a starting point.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing the Active Directory could do.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a plan yet.  That question would be better for SF.  Once you have a plan for locking out non-admins, you can ask here if you run into problems coding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all the users with NetUserEnum, and for those that are non-admins disable their account using NetUserSetInfo with the the USER_INFO_1 struct and the UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE flag.  Keep a list of the users you disable so that when you're done you can reenable their accounts.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: By "reverse the process", do you mean "enumerate and enable all non-admin users"?  That sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: No of course not.  Just keep a list of the users you disabled it and use that.  But I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: I've used these functions in a domain.  Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: My original reasoning: because the application would have to disable the domain accounts, which (a) it probably shouldn't have privilege to do; and (b) would prevent the users from logging into *any* machine, not just the one they're supposed to be locked out of.

Comment: However, rereading the question I note that the OP doesn't make it clear whether he wants the users locked out of just one machine (as I assumed) or the entire domain.  Similarly it depends upon the function of the application whether or not it naturally has domain admin privilege.  So it depends on the interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to get the administrator to create a local group containing a list of users who should be able to log in normally, and to assign the "log in locally" right to only this group and the Administrators group.

You could then use [LsaRemoveAccountRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LsaAddAccountRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to toggle the "log in locally" right to the local group.

I suggest you get the administrator to do the initial changes, because messing with user rights without the administrator's knowledge and consent will upset people and could cause unexpected side-effects.